# Assign new points of mixed data type to existing PAM generated cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to assign new data to existing clusters I have numerical and categorical data types. The example below is similar to my process. The data frame "newdf" are the points I would like to assign to the PAM clusters, how would I code this in R? Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
set.seed(1680)

library(dplyr) 
library(ISLR) 
library(cluster) 

college_clean <- College %>%
  mutate(name = row.names(.),
         accept_rate = Accept/Apps,
         isElite = cut(Top10perc,
                       breaks = c(0, 50, 100),
                       labels = c("Not Elite", "Elite"),
                       include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(isElite = factor(isElite)) %>%
  select(name, accept_rate, Outstate, Enroll,
         Grad.Rate, Private, isElite)



gower_dist <- daisy(college_clean[,-1],
                    metric = "gower",
                    type = list(logratio = 3))
pam_fit <- pam(gower_dist, diss = TRUE, k = 3)


newdf=data.frame(name=c("x_university","y_university","z_university"),
                accept_rate=c(.73,.50,.98),Outstate=c(10000,15000,5000),
                Enroll=c(500,1000,200),Grad.Rate=c(80,65,73),
                Private=c("Yes","No","No"),isElite=c("Elite","Not Elite", "Elite"))
```

Answer (score -1):

It's really straightforward, just do it.

Argmin of the distance to the cluster medoids.

Comment: Thanks, for my own clarification or a later viewer could it be implemented like so. 
  `medoids=pam_fit$medoids
assignCluster=rbind(college_clean[medoids,-1],newdf[1,-1])
assignclusterDist=daisy(assignCluster,metric = "gower",
                   type = list(logratio = 3))`
and taking  the min dissimilarity as the cluster the new point belongs to?

Comment: I don't use R, I don't know if you can do this more elegantly.